# Problem with tangents

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

If $\tan\alpha=3$ and $\tan\beta=2$.  ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in first quadrant).

> Prove that  $$\frac{\pi}{24}<\alpha-\beta< \frac{\pi}{16}$$

And I get that $$\tan(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{1}{7}$$
But I can't continue

Comment: By periodicity you can take $\beta$ to be arbitrarily large, so this is false.

Comment: @HenryW. yes, that is true, but what if we restrict the angles only to the first quadrant? Then it is an interesting question I think!

Comment: @HenryW. It is not my question :)

Comment: Off the bat, in terms of degrees $\alpha-\beta$ turns out to be approx 8.13 degrees which is between the two given angles in the inequality...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my start on this problem: We need exact answers of trig values through half angle formulas. Using some older trig research, we know that $\sin22.5=\sqrt{\frac{1-0.5\sqrt{2}}{2}}$ and $\cos22.5=\sqrt{\frac{1+0.5\sqrt{2}}{2}}$. This enables us to get an exact value for $tan11.25$ which comes (through it half angle formula $\frac{\sin...}{1+\cos...}$) to be $\frac{\sqrt{1-.5\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{1+.5\sqrt{2}}}$ This is the upper value of the inequality (It is a bit more than $1/7$).

Similarly for the lower given angle, I find $\tan7.5=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4+\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}$. This value is indeed a bit less than 1/7 The problem now is to show numerically that the inequality holds. I am still stuck on that, but there is no trig involved. If someone can add to my solution, that would be great. If it is believed that my approach leads to nothing, then let me know, I will take it off!

Comment: If $\tan(\pi/24) < 1/7 < \tan(\pi/16)$ (as you've shown), then $\tan$ monotonic in the first quadrant, then it is proved.

Comment: Makes sense....but I was thinking of a way to show the truth of my last inequality that does not involve trig anymore. It is all squareroots and stuff. It is a daunting task to show that 1/7 is between those two irrational expressions

Answer (score 0):

**This is not yet an answer but hopefully sheds some light.**

Looking at the numbers, I think this has something to do with $\pi/8$ because:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{16} &= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\pi}{8} \\
\frac{\pi}{24} &= \frac{1}{3} \frac{\pi}{8}
\end{align}
$$

$\tan(\pi/8)$ can be found using half-angle equations: [Trigonometry Angles--Pi/8](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi8.html). We can do the same thing for [$\pi/16$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi16.html) and [$\pi/24$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi24.html).

Comment: Would you be so kind to read my approach, maybe you can add something...

Answer (score -2):

This is how I understood it. You need first to find the values of alpha and beta. Using the formula alpha=Arctan 3 and beta=Arctan 2 . After getting the values of the two subtract beta to alpha and you will get the answer that  will satisfy what you are proving.

Comment: Yes, my dear. we also figured that out...But we need exact values for "alpha" and "beta" Putting stuff into the calculator is not considered a proof.

Comment: Although it is not stated, it is implied that the answer must use logical reasoning and trigonometry but no calculations that would require a calculator. Your answer does not meet that implied requirement.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I gave it a try to get somewhere. I am kindly asking your thoughts on it...